# ¿Por qué me sale este error? ¿Qué significa?

Tags: html, vscode, vscode-live-server

La verdad, ya busqué qué significa ese error en MDN e intenté con varios navegadores pero como ven, soy bastante inexperto. En el curso que estoy haciendo el instructor lo instala con node.js, lo cual intenté pero no me salió, e instalé la extensión que se supone que era la forma "fácil" pero aunque se actualice en tiempo real la página para evitar refrescarla manualmente, es incomodo ver ese error ahí todo el rato y no quisiera que me generara problemas para un futuro, sé que algo hice mal, así que si me pueden echar una mano, lo agradecería. EL error se muestra en la consola, al final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y el código que genera esto es?

Comment: significa que no encuentra el archivo `/favicon.ico` que seguramente esté definido en el html en la sección `<head>` verifica que haya un archivo `favicon.ico` si no hay uno lo generas con algún [generador online u offline](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+open+source+favicon.ico+generator) ( es el icono que aparecerá en la pestaña al lado del título, también usado según el sistema operativo y el manejador de archivos o escritorio si arrastras el enlace al escritorio o creando un acceso directo etc )

Comment: No tiene ni porque estar en tu código ese archivo /favicon.ico, sinó que si te has agregado esa url a tus favoritos el navegador lo pide para ponerlo en la pestaña, y si no lo encuentra pone uno genérico.

Comment: Recomendación: Estudia sobre "errores HTTP" y aprende su significado, y si no los quieres aprender/estudiar, no pasa nada, mientras tengas acceso a internet, puedes buscar y leer tantas veces hagan falta para que sepas lo que está ocurriendo entre el cliente (la web que estás haciendo) y el server (lo que genera `express.js`).

Comment: Gracias!! Me ayudaste bastante